# kpsewhich returns blank line

Tags: miktex

When I run

```
kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME
```

in the command prompt on Windows 10, a blank line is returned (i.e. two blank lines between the command and the next prompt). It is not an error (`kpsewhich` is on the path, as are all `latex` commands, which work as expected).

I tried running as an administrator, running in a different directory, and updating my MikTeX distribution. How should I troubleshoot this further? I believe I know my `latex` folder, but now I'm not so sure...

Comment: Have you created a local tree and added it to MiKTeX? Unlike TeX Live, MiKTeX starts of with no pre-defined user tree

Comment: No, I haven't done that. So a blank response is the expected behaviour for MikTeX?

Comment: IMHO that's normal - a blank line means that kpsewhich doesn't know the variable. But I can't test now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows you can get the names of used directorys by using the application/programm `MiKTeX Settings (Admin)` for the administrator account and `MiXTeX Settings` for the user account.

Click on `Roots` to view the used directorys for MiKTeX. Don't forget to check box "show MiKTeX-maintained root directorys".

[image: root directorys]

Comment: Any settings for the environmental variable `TEXMFHOME` also apply and do not show up in the dialog.