# Creating new single line classes in ODT output from mk4ht oolatex

Tags: compiling, tex4ht, make4ht, css

I've been trying to follow a tutorial here:  github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht/wiki/tex4ht-tutorial

My MWE files below produce a valid output with the text from the command, but I was expecting the class (i.e. the document style for this text) to be assigned in accordance with the command used, similar to the way this ([Customizing ODT output from mk4ht oolatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427528/customizing-odt-output-from-mk4ht-oolatex)) example used environments to change the class which corresponded to a style name in the associated word file (referenced in the build instruction odttemplate). I can't, however, tell if the code is unable to interrupt the body text style or whether the style is not being assigned because of an error in the code.

> Main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{testpkg}
\begin{document} 

    Test

    Some text in English, 

    \SectionTitleTest{Test}

    More text

\end{document}
```

> testpkg.sty

```
\ProvidesPackage{testpkg} 

    \RequirePackage{xparse,expl3}
    \DeclareDocumentCommand{\SectionTitleTest}{m}{#1}

\endinput
```

> testpkg.cfg

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

% to simplify things
\def\myendpar{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP}

\Configure{SectionTitleTest}{\HCode{<span class="SectionTitleTest">}\NoFonts}{\EndNoFonts\HCode{</span>}}% tried without NoFonts code to no avail either
\Css{.SectionTitleTest{font-style:SectionTitleTest;}}

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

> testpkg.4ht

```
% provide configure for new command. we can choose any name
% but most convenient is to name hooks after redefined command
% we declare two hooks, to be inserted before and after the command

\NewConfigure{SectionTitleTest}{2}

% now we need to redefine \SectionTitleTest. save it to tmp command
% note that `:` can be part of command name in `.4ht` files.
\let\tmp:SectionTitleTest\SectionTitleTest

% now insert the hooks. they are named as \a:hook, \b:hook, ..., \h:hook
% depending on how many hooks were declared

\renewcommand\SectionTitleTest{\a:SectionTitleTest\tmp:SectionTitleTest\b:SectionTitleTest}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your configuration. Fist of all, in `testpkg.4ht`:

```
\renewcommand\SectionTitleTest{\a:SectionTitleTest\tmp:SectionTitleTest\b:SectionTitleTest}
```

The original `\SectionTitleTest` takes one argument, but you redefine it as argument free. Because of this, all content of the configuration is inserted before the text you pass as argument to `\SectionTitleTest`. The correct redefinition would look like this:

```
% provide configure for new command. we can choose any name
% but most convenient is to name hooks after redefined command
% we declare two hooks, to be inserted before and after the command

\NewConfigure{SectionTitleTest}{2}

% now we need to redefine \SectionTitleTest. save it to tmp command
% note that `:` can be part of command name in `.4ht` files.
\let\tmp:SectionTitleTest\SectionTitleTest

% now insert the hooks. they are named as \a:hook, \b:hook, ..., \h:hook
% depending on how many hooks were declared

\renewcommand\SectionTitleTest[1]{\a:SectionTitleTest\tmp:SectionTitleTest{#1}\b:SectionTitleTest}
```

The second issue is that you use HTML tags. In the ODT output, you must use [OpenDocument tags](http://docs.oasis-open.org/office/v1.2/os/OpenDocument-v1.2-os-part1.html). Also, ODT doesn't support CSS, it uses special XML instead.

The updated `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

% to simplify things
\def\myendpar{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP}

\Configure{SectionTitleTest}{\myendpar\HCode{<text:p text:style-name="section-title">}}{\HCode{</text:p>}}
\NewConfigureOO{section-title}
\ConfigureOO{section-title}{<style:style style:name="section-title" style:family="paragraph" style:class="text">
    <style:text-properties style:text-underline-style="solid"
                           style:text-underline-width="auto"
                           style:text-underline-color="font-color"
    />
</style:style>}

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

The `<text:p>` element is used for paragraphs. It needs to use the `text:style-name` attribute to select the  paragraph style.

The paragraph style is defined using `\NewConfigureOO` and configured using `\ConfigureOO`. I've used the same name as in `text:style-name`, but it is not necessary. The correct style name must be used `<style:style style:name="section-title">` though.

The provided style configures the section title to produce underlined text. Use [`<style:text-properties>` attributes](http://docs.oasis-open.org/office/v1.2/os/OpenDocument-v1.2-os-part1.html#__RefHeading__1416402_253892949) to change the formatting according to your needs.

This is the result in LO:

[image]

Comment: Are the redefinitions in the 4ht file, and the NewConfigureOO & ConfigureOO in the config file, necessary if the command was a basic command like `\section{}` which I just want to remap to a style in an odt file that would be identified through the compile command `--format odt+odttemplate` + `odttemplate=template.odt`?  For example, I may have `\section{introduction}` in latex, but my organization's document template may not expect me to use `Heading-2` but `CustomSectionHeading -2`. I'm hoping not to have to create 4ht and sty files except for custom commands separately packaged. Thanks!

Comment: @EngBIRD sorry for the late reply. you can then configure just the section in the `.cfg` file. Look for `\Configure{section}` in `ooffice.4ht`, copy it and change the `text:style-name` attribute to a new name.

Comment: Thanks, I've found the file and the command, it's definitely more fulsome than my first attempt. I had tried `\def\myendpar{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP} \Configure{section}{\myendpar\HCode{<text:p text:style-name="Illustration">}}{\HCode{</text:p>}}` which didn't work.  There are two text:style blocks so I'll play around with which I substitute before confirming my success.

Comment: @EngBIRD I think you should pass four parameters to `\Configure{section}`, not just two.

Comment: I am a bit lost in the comments, sorry. Maybe it would be best to post it as a new question?

Comment: Thanks for looking, I've cleaned up the comments and posted a new question:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559032/customizing-existing-single-line-classes-in-odt-output-from-mk4ht-oolatex . Thanks for your help.