# Customizing existing single line classes in ODT output from mk4ht oolatex

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

As an extension to this question:  [Creating new single line classes in ODT output from mk4ht oolatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529073/customizing-single-line-classes-in-odt-output-from-mk4ht-oolatex/529105?noredirect=1#comment1397046_529105)

I've been attempting to use this approach to reassign the style assigned in existing commands that have already been configured. The initial guidance provided in the comments of the linked question suggested starting from the `\Configure{section}` command found in `ooffice.4ht`

```
\Configure{section}
   {\IgnorePar\EndP \HCode{<!--start of section-->}}
   {\IgnorePar\EndP \HCode{<!--end of section-->}}
   {\HCode{<text:h
            text:style-name="\csname a:Heading-2\if@rl-rtl\fi
\endcsname"
                   \text:outlinelevel="2" ><text:span
                   text:style-name="section" >}\TitleMark\space
    \HCode{</text:span>}\IgnoreIndent}
   {\HCode{</text:h>\Hnewline}\par\ShowPar}
```

So I started playing around with this block as a starting point. But I've been unable to get this block to compile let alone customize with my own style names. I've tried to many permutations and scope changes to detail each here, but in short, I've tried:

1. simplifying the `csname` line to only contain my desired section name.
2. I've removed TeX code like the `\TitleMark` and `\space`.
3. I've also tried replacing the `HCode` portions with the customized `HCode` text inspired from the answer to the related question.
4. My setup seems sensitive to spaces so I've been playing around with this and `%` on line endings as well.

I get error messages at times complaining about the `:h` and the associated `>` character, but in general it only reports the typical `Missing \begin{document} in myconfig.cfg`

MWE:

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{specialtextcolor}{rgb}{0,0,1}

\newenvironment{test}
{\par\begin{color}{specialtextcolor}}
{\end{color}}


\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    
\begin{document}
    
This is a normal paragraph.

\section{Custom style access test}

test text in the first level of section hierarchy 

more text

\begin{test}
    This is a test environment.
\end{test}    

more text

This is a blockquote environment

\begin{quote}
    This is a test quote environment.
\end{quote}    
    
\end{document}
```

**myconfig.cfg**

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
% to simplify the things
\def\myendpar{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP}

% configure the single line commands in Tex against their corresponding style in the template

\Configure{section}%
{\IgnorePar\EndP \HCode{<!--start of section-->}}%
{\IgnorePar\EndP \HCode{<!--end of section-->}}%
{\HCode{<text:h
        text:style-name="Heading-2">
        text:outlinelevel="2" ><text:span
        text:style-name="section" >}%
    %\TitleMark\space%
    \HCode{</text:span>}%
    %\IgnoreIndent%
}%
{\HCode{</text:h>\Hnewline}\par\ShowPar}%


% configure the environments in Tex against their corresponding style in the template
\ConfigureEnv{test}%
{%
    \myendpar\bgroup%
    % when you want to modify the paragraph style, you must redefine the paragraph configuration to use the test style name
    \Configure{HtmlPar}%
        {\EndP \HCode{<text:p text:style-name="test">}}%
        {\EndP \HCode{<text:p text:style-name="test">}}%
        {\HCode{</text:p>}}%
        {\HCode{</text:p>}}%
    \par\ShowPar%
}{\myendpar\egroup}{}{}%


\ConfigureEnv{quote}%
{%
    \myendpar\bgroup%
    % when you want to modify the paragraph style, you must redefine the paragraph configuration to use the test style name
    \Configure{HtmlPar}%
        {\EndP \HCode{<text:p text:style-name="quote">}}%
        {\EndP \HCode{<text:p text:style-name="quote">}}%
        {\HCode{</text:p>}}%
        {\HCode{</text:p>}}%
    \par\ShowPar%
}{\myendpar\egroup}{}{}%




\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

The example is compiled against a sample ODT template file with the command:

- as part of a linux shell script: `make4ht -u --config "myconfig.cfg" --format "odt+odttemplate" "$FILE" odttemplate="$BASEDIR/refTemplates/basic.odt"`
- or as part of a bat file on windows: `"%MikTexPath%%htxCompiler%" --config "myconfig.cfg" --format "odt+odttemplate" "%%~nxA" odttemplate="./refTemplates/basic.odt"`

If I've completely missed the mark, how else could I change the mapping of styles in existing commands?

Comment: What should `\Configure{SectionTitleTest}` do? It isn't defined anywhere and it gives you the compilation error. There are also other issues that I will investigate, but this one can be fixed just by removing of this line.

Comment: do you want to use the `section-title` style in `\Configure{section}`?

Comment: @michal.h21 Ah, my apologies, it can be removed at the moment, it was part of the file as inspired by the first and linked question. I kept it because I was using it as an example of what the Hcode blocks might have needed to look like as I modified the \Configure{section} block to look more like it. I think I must have messed up the MWE as on my computer if I comment out the `\Configure{section}` block it compiles fine.

Comment: I think I've identified the issues, will post my answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get errors with your `mwe.cfg` mainly because: you use undeclared `\Configure{SectionTitleTest}` and because of missing fifth argument for `\Configure{section}`.

I can compile your file with the following fixes:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
% to simplify the things
\def\myendpar{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP}

% configure the single line commands in Tex against their corresponding style in the template

%\Configure{SectionTitleTest}{\myendpar\HCode{<text:p text:style-name="section-title">}}{\HCode{</text:p>}}
\NewConfigureOO{section-title}
\ConfigureOO{section-title}{<style:style style:name="section-title" style:family="paragraph" style:class="text">
    <style:text-properties style:text-underline-style="solid"   
    style:text-underline-width="auto"
    style:text-underline-color="font-color"   
    />
    </style:style>}


\Configure{section}%
{\IgnorePar\EndP \HCode{<!--start of section-->}}%
{\IgnorePar\EndP \HCode{<!--end of section-->}}%
{\HCode{<text:h
        text:style-name="Heading 1"
        text:outlinelevel="2" ><text:span
        text:style-name="section" >}%
    %\TitleMark\space%
    \HCode{</text:span>}%
    %\IgnoreIndent%
}{\HCode{</text:h>}}%

% \Configure{section}
%    {\IgnorePar\EndP \HCode{<!--start of section-->}}
%    {\IgnorePar\EndP \HCode{<!--end of section-->}}
%    {\HCode{<text:h
%             text:style-name="\csname a:Heading-2\if@rl-rtl\fi\endcsname"
%                    text:outlinelevel="2" ><text:span
%                    text:style-name="section" >}\TitleMark\space
%     \HCode{</text:span>}\IgnoreIndent}
%    {\HCode{</text:h>\Hnewline}\par\ShowPar}


% configure the environments in Tex against their corresponding style in the template
\ConfigureEnv{test}%
{%
    \myendpar\bgroup%
    % when you want to modify the paragraph style, you must redefine the paragraph configuration to use the test style name
    \Configure{HtmlPar}%
        {\EndP \HCode{<text:p text:style-name="test">}}%
        {\EndP \HCode{<text:p text:style-name="test">}}%
        {\HCode{</text:p>}}%
        {\HCode{</text:p>}}%
    \par\ShowPar%
}{\myendpar\egroup}{}{}%


\ConfigureEnv{quote}%
{%
    \myendpar\bgroup%
    % when you want to modify the paragraph style, you must redefine the paragraph configuration to use the test style name
    \Configure{HtmlPar}%
        {\EndP \HCode{<text:p text:style-name="quote">}}%
        {\EndP \HCode{<text:p text:style-name="quote">}}%
        {\HCode{</text:p>}}%
        {\HCode{</text:p>}}%
    \ShowPar%
}{\myendpar\egroup}{}{}%


\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

Another fix I've added was that I removed `\par` from `\ConfigureEnv{quote}`, because this resulted in spurious empty paragraph that showed in the document.

This is the rendered document:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I've updated my question with `{\HCode{</text:h>\Hnewline}\par\ShowPar}%` - the 5th argument from my MWE that I mistakenly deleted when I was clearing out commented out code from past attempts in my actual config file.  Unfortunately I'm still getting errors:  `Paragraph ended before \HCode was complete`, `LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in myconfig.cfg`, and `Too many }s.`.  Since this is a copy paste from your cfg file, I know the error must be else where, so I'll report back when I've looked for brace mismatches elsewhere in the file.

Comment: @EngBIRD maybe you still have the `\Configure{SectionTitleTest}` in your config file? This may cause the 'missing \begin{document}` error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In light of the config file you provided in your answer though I started from a clean file which has removed this mistake.

Comment: @EngBIRD can you post your updated `.cfg` file? It seems the one provided in your question still has the `\Configure{SectionTitleTest}` line.

Comment: Thanks again for all your amazing help and work on this package, it's working now.  I didn't change anything from last night, just a clean reboot of the computer... So something must have changed.  Only thing I can think of is if somehow, and I feel stupid theorizing things that make no sense against how computers work, but I'm wondering if in memory the `SectionTitleTest` was still in memory somewhere and not finding the necessary `4ht` files, as I did remove this file the when starting from your complete, new cfg file without this residual custom command.

Comment: @EngBIRD I am glad it works now. Bugs are sometimes just mysterious :)

Comment: Speaking of mysterious bugs, I can't compile this or other past solutions on windows. Are you aware of any changes to the base of the make4ht or related that would be causing the compiler to think it or other files are on network drives? I've been getting this error for many months now. `'\\?\C:\Home\Personal\Dropbox\Tex_Work\MWE-odt\COMPILE_OUTPUT' CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory. The system cannot find the file specified. [STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion finished` Probably merits it's own question...

Comment: @EngBIRD I don't use Windows at all, but it seems like the Windows's CMD itself thinks your files are UNC. I had even to Google what UNC is :) Anyway, have you tried some of these suggestions? https://serverfault.com/q/50085

Comment: I have googled, but no luck yet.  It's interesting because I'm not using a network drive, but the compile engine things it's being run from one (see the `\\?\ `in front of my C drive in the error message above). I haven't posted this as a distinct question because it's not probably not reproducible. It happened after an update sometime late in 2019 if memory serves, works fine on Linux, and surely would be more prevalently reported here if it was a make4ht bug.  So thanks for commenting on my tangent, and for your help with my issue above!

Comment: I still don't think I have enough information to post a new question, but a quick update to this UNC issue. I've managed to determine that the problem appears to be specific to the `odt+template` compile option. Location of the template odt file doesn't seem to matter, but if I compile on windows without this option it appears to work fine, just doesn't come with the expected style customizations other than those in the cfg file. I've tried creating my target template odt file a few different ways with no difference in the compile error and these exact template files have worked previously.

Comment: @EngBIRD the strange thing is that `make4ht` doesn't do anything with the template filename, it just uses regular Lua functions to read that file. See https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht/blob/3d97d239125f017a644532228c28d45d84f338fc/filters/make4ht-odttemplate.lua#L6

Comment: Indeed it's quite bizarre. I recognize this lua file, I looked at it on my own tex installations when I was checking if my linux machine and windows machines were using different versions of make4ht.  I saw the regex like string matching and figured there was nothing that was adding slashes or something that could be confused with a server address. I'd be surprised if make4ht was the problem, it worked fine for years, the only thing I ever updated during that time was my open office installation. Then again, I update the linux open office way more often so maybe that's not the issue either.

Comment: @EngBIRD it must be some Windows update issue, I think. Maybe try a different  quotes? like `make4ht -f odt+odttemplate filename.tex "odttemplate=mytemplate.odt'`.

Comment: Update:  Looks like I didn't quite break the problem down quite far enough, the problem is actually further upstream of the template in the compile instruction, it's with `--format odt`.  `--format XXX` works fine for each html5, tei, xhtml, and docbook.  The odt option is the only one causing a UNC problem.  Could this indicate a problem with my libre office installation?  Or is the make4ht compile format independent of having libre office installed?  I think I read that libre office is only needed if your using it to do a headless docx conversion. Thanks!

Comment: @EngBIRD I think this is the same issue: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/563644/2891. It doesn't happen with TeX Live on Windows, so I think it is caused by something in Miktex.

Comment: @EngBIRD it may be worth to report it on Miktex issue tracker.