# tex4ebook can't change directory because of UNC paths

Tags: luatex, miktex, tex4ebook, make4ht, epub

I had used `tex4ebook` to make an `epub3` book about two years ago. After updating my `MikTeX`, and moving to the `book` directory, I tried to remake the `epub` file using the command:

```
cd \Users\me\Documents\book
tex4ebook -c config.cfg mybook
```

The error I got was:

```
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion started
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Input file: mybook
'\\?\C:\Users\me\Documents\book'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

It appears as if the simple path `C:\Users\me\Documents\book` got mangled to a UNC (network) path, and
`CMD.EXE` does not like a path starting with `\\`. So, instead of starting in the appropriate directory, it starts in the `C:\Windows` directory, and hence can't create any files, and can't find any files.

I presume I could fix this problem by going into Administrator mode and moving all the book files to `C:\Windows`, but that probably is not the recommended solution :)

Comment: Does this happen also with `make4ht`? I had similar report recently, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: anyway, could you please post also output of `tex4ebook -a debug -c config.cfg mybook`? It should tell us where it fails.

Comment: @michal.h21 `make4ht` worked, giving a warning `[WARNING] domfilter: DOM parsing of SFET.html failed:`
`[WARNING] domfilter: ...Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/center) [char=682913]`

Comment: This is some other issue, I would need to see your file to guess what is wrong.

Comment: anyway, it seems that this happens only with Miktex, not with TeX Live.

Comment: I have same problem.

Comment: @JardaFait It seems TeX4ht was udpated in Miktex in the past weeks. Do you still get errors?

Comment: @michal.h21 My errors have disappeared, after the update.

Comment: @RoobieNuby that's great to hear :)

Comment: The issue had been fixed by the Miktex update